# How much info can you pull out of facebook?

Tags: api, facebook, integration

We're interested in incorporating a lot of the facebook info in our application. So for example we want to display your wall's content as part of our UI combined with other stuff etc.

With facebook connect how much data can we pull from facebook? Is everything available programatically, including wall feeds, profiles, pictures, etc? Does facebook connect simply opens up an html to facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wall content and information like that is available but only if the user grants you access. When you create a FB application (whenever you need to get an app ID), when people click, you can ask them to grant certain permissions beyond basic permissions. For example, email address or publishing to their wall or offline access, etc. If you have all the permissions, you'll be good to go. However, people tend to freak out when some website is asking for all those permissions. You will probably deter signups if you ask for all the permissions at once.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at http://developers.facebook.com/ ?